# SSD seems to be read-only, nothing can be written to it (linux ext4 filesystem)

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd, filesystems, ext4

After two week of normal use my new SSD began to work strange. Now it seems that no file is written to it.
An example:

```
root@hooker3:~# mount |grep ssdhome
/dev/sda3 on /ssdhome type ext4 (rw,nosuid,noatime,data=ordered)
root@hooker3:~# ls -l /ssdhome/
total 16
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Jan 19 20:21 lost+found
root@hooker3:~# echo apple >/ssdhome/test_file
root@hooker3:~# ls -l /ssdhome/test_file 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6 Jan 24 20:01 /ssdhome/test_file
root@hooker3:~# cat /ssdhome/test_file 
apple
root@hooker3:~# umount /ssdhome
root@hooker3:~# mount /ssdhome
root@hooker3:~# ls -l /ssdhome/test_file 
ls: cannot access /ssdhome/test_file: No such file or directory
```

Until a remount everything looks normal, but after a remount a previous state of the file system comes back.
Similar happens when the cache is emptied (echo 3 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches). The difference is that after empty the cache the file still exists but its contents is some trash, while the file system becomes read-only.
So nothing can be written to the device permanently as after a reboot every new data is lost. There are two ext4 fs on the device and both became read-only.

The SSD is an ADATA S596. OS is Debian 8.
Even reformatting doesn't help, moreover after repartition and reformat nothing change on the device. (It means that OS reinstall is impossible!?)

Not much before the first sign of the problem I run an fstrim command on the root partition (which freed 9GB data). Might be it related to this problem?
By the way the first fstrim after a reboot or remount always says that the same amount (9GB) is trimmed which seems fail.

What can I do? Might be it a hardware error?